# Getting Null pointer exception while running my code

Tags: selenium

I am getting the null  pointer error in the below code. If you run the code it will execute all the code just before the code where i mentioned 'captureScreenshot()' function after this its not executing.

```
 package rough;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;



public class TestEmailAndScreenshot1 {

public static WebDriver  dr;
public static String mailscreenshotpath;

public static void captureScreenshot(){


    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int sec = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    int min = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int date = cal.get(Calendar.DATE);
    int day = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);


    File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)dr).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    try {
         mailscreenshotpath =            System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\screenshot\\"+year+"_"+date+"_"+(month+1)+"_"+day+"_"+min+"_" +sec+".jpeg";
        FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File(mailscreenshotpath));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

        }
}



 public static void main(String[] args) {

    WebDriver dr=new FirefoxDriver();
    dr.manage().window().maximize();    
    dr.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    dr.get("http://gmail.com");
    dr.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("vijenderchhoker92");
   captureScreenshot();
 System.out.println(" Screenshot taken successfully....");

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
WebDriver dr = new FirefoxDriver();
```

In `main` you hide the `public static WebDriver dr;` variable, so in `captureScreenshot()` method it's still `null` and you get the error trying to use it. Change to

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    dr = new FirefoxDriver();
    dr.manage().window().maximize();
    //...
}
```